# Why union generic constraint behaves weird in TS?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function that combines the values of string|number arrays. So after trying extending generic param with union type I get weird behaviour which I don't understand. In some cases only the first item's values are being picked up for type checking, sometimes both.

Here is an example

```
type StringOrNumber = string | number;

const concat = <T extends StringOrNumber>(a: T[], b: T[]): T[] => [...a, ...b];

const badResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2"]);
const anotherBadResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2", 1, 5]);
const okResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2", 4, 5]);
```

I expect the function to take arrays of string or number values and the result to be either string[], number[] or string|number[].

I know that it's possible to just use the union type everywhere, but the result would always be string|number, which is not what I want.

Thank You

Comment: It behaves "weird" because once you declare `a` to be `[1, 4]`, then TypeScript thinks `T` equals type `[1, 4]` and will error at parameter `b` expecting a type with `[1, 4]`, but it gets `[1, "2"]` instead. That's why your `okResult` doesn't error, because `b` contains `1` and `4`.

Comment: @CoderApprentice - I thought it was based just on the first argument's type too, but it isn't. Try changing the `"2` in the first example to a `7`, for instance. The inference changes from `1 | 4` to `1 | 4 | 7`, even though in the OP's original example, it isn't `1 | 4 | "2"`, it's just `1 | 4`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hmm you're correct. It's weird cuz my TS says that argument `b` is also of type `[1, 4]` even though it doesn't have a `4`. For you it infers to `1 | 4 | 7` ? I think we have different TS versions as well, which makes this more confusing.

Comment: @CoderApprentice - The `7` is from **my** change to the OP's code, see [comments below starting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75310313/why-union-generic-constraint-behaves-weird-in-ts?noredirect=1#comment132888355_75310382).

Comment: So this a "why" question? Or a "how can I do this so it works" question? If it's the former then it's probably some hairy heuristic (see links in [this github issue comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49850#issuecomment-1180466141)), whereby `string` or string literals from one inference site and `number` or number literals from another inference site tends to be rejected... because normally people want to disallow such things, two different arguments with two "unrelated" types. The last case presumably works because one type completely extends the other.

Comment: ^ I could write that up as an answer with as many sources as I can find, but I don't know how authoritative it can be. The only thing I can say for sure with 100% confidence is: TypeScript type argument inference depends on heuristic rules which behave well over a wide range of use cases but occasionally produce undesirable results, at which point you need to work around them.  How should I proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz I would be interested in the "why" and I'm guessing T.J. Crowder would be as well ;)

Comment: ^ I think I've mostly already addressed why in my comments, and right now I'm waiting to see whether that's actually what the question is asking.  The title says "why" but the body of the question isn't directly asking a question, so I'd like to see it [edit]ed to something explicit, like "why is this happening" or "how can I get my desired behavior" before I spend a lot of time writing up an answer that doesn't necessarily target the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use [variadic tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) syntax:

```js
type StringOrNumber = string | number;

const concat = <
    A extends StringOrNumber[],
    B extends StringOrNumber[]
>(a: [...A], b: [...B]): [...A, ...B] => [...a, ...b];

const badResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2"]); // [1, 4, 1, "2"]
const anotherBadResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2", 1, 5]);
const okResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2", 4, 5]);
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbK7BW)

Lets analyze original OP's code:

```js
type StringOrNumber = string | number;

const concat = <T extends StringOrNumber>(a: T[], b: T[]): T[] => [...a, ...b];

const badResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2"]); // error

const anotherBadResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2", 1, 5]); // error

const okResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2", 1, 4]); // ok

const _ = concat([1, 4,], [1, 7, 2, 5]); // ok
```

WHen first argument includes only numbers, second argument should also includes only numbers (does not matter whether it is 1,4, 9 or any other number). It just should be a subtype of a number. Once, you provide string number `"2"` to the second argument, TS allows you to use only a subtype of literal number type, in other words only `1 | 4` are allowed, all other values will be highlighted as an error.

COnsider this:

```js
concat([1, "2"], [9, "2", 9, 4]); // ok
```

If you provide a stringified number to the first argument, TS allows you to use `string | number` in both arrays.

To summarize, elements in the first array will define elements in the second array.

Inference algorithm start from the left side and goes to the right. If you want to change this direction, you can use this :

```js
type StringOrNumber = string | number;

const concat = <T extends StringOrNumber>(a: (T & {})[], b: T[]): T[] => [...a, ...b];

const badResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2"]); // error

const anotherBadResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2", 1, 5]); // error

const okResult = concat([1, 4], [1, "2", 1, 4]); // ok
```

Then you will get similar behaviour, but first argument will be disallowed instead of second. THis is because inference starts from the `b` argument and only then checks `a` argument.

Comment: But **why** does it behave this way in the first place? The OP's first example shows it infers `1 | 4` as the type argument, which would suggest it's based on just the first argument's type -- but then that suggestion is contradicted by the fact that if I change `"2"` to `7` in that example (in the second argument), the inference changes to `1 | 4 | 7`. So the second argument is considered, but a string isn't allowed. ??

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my bad, provided an explanation. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused by my `concat([1, 4], [1, 7])` example (which works, inferring `1 | 4 | 7` instead of `1 | 4`). Based on *"...second argument b elements should be a subtype of first one, and it is not. `1 | "2"` is not a subtype of `1 | 4`..."* shouldn't my example fail because `1 | 7` isn't a subtype of `1 | 4`? But instead, the compiler broadens the `1 | 4` to include `7` (but won't do that for a non-number). Similarly, I don't get `concat([1, 4], [3, "2"])`, which shows errors not only on the `"2"` but on the `3` as well. !?!?! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point. My answer was partially incorrect and looks like incomplete

Comment: If **you're** struggling with this, the rest of us are in trouble! :-D Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: I think it is somewhat related to this example: https://tsplay.dev/mAdlQN. The compiler seems to prefer homogeneous unions while trying to infer a generic type based on multiple targets.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder most of the time I know how to make things work, but not always I clearly understand how it works under the hood. Several times I tried to read source code of TS but it is too complicated for me

Comment: thanks for a better solution that works. Though in some cases it still is not clear why some possible examples are accepted in the original code. Not important though. I guess it is something that is not an intended feature of TS (in this case) and it's just accidental that it goes through.

Comment: @VladasK- the problem is that TypeScript don't have a specification like, for instance, JS has